# Is it appropriate to conclude the relationship "does not matter" because the regression coefficient is not significant?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, regression-coefficients

Many papers (e.g. apps.washingtonpost.com/g/documents/national/does-the-amount-of-time-mothers-spend-with-children-or-adolescents-matter/1490/) try to claim an insignificant regression coefficient implied the IV has no effect on the DV. Yet how is this differ from the reasoning that "when we can we cannot reject the Null hypothesis, we cannot say we accept the null hypothesis" in hypothesis testing?

I know this may sounds like a wording issues, but when we teach introductory class, we have been emphasis so much to students that we cannot accept the null hypothesis as conceptually it is simply wrong, yet, saying something "did not matter", "no association" sounds like accepting the null hypothesis....

[image: Sample Abstract]

Comment: I think you are correct in your view that it is inappropriate, particularly since there may have been unmeasured confounders or other factors which can also bias regression coefficients.

Comment: @tristan, I think it hard to explain to students why so many papers are doing this while I tell them not to accept null hypothesis... Plus so many people are doing this makes me wonder if this is actually appropriate...

Comment: Reporting confidence intervals gives a useful measure of uncertainty in this situation. A 95% CI for correlation between -0.01 and 0.03 would be non-significant and "doesn't matter" might be an adequate two word summary. But from -0.1 to 0.3, a more nuanced interpretation of significance would be helpful.

Comment: There are some situations, for example, where power calculations are performed based on a minimal important difference, where you can state the probability of making a Type II error. If your power is 95% and upwards you might be confident in "accepting" the null hypothesis, but usually I see power calculations based on 80% power or maybe 90%. Also the point still stands that the statistical model may have been misspecified and therefore biased.

Comment: I agree with using power and CI to interpret the results too.... yet seems using p value to reject hypothesis and then "accepting the null hypothesis" is still so prominent in the field....